# How do you express a chuckle in a text bubble in a comic?

Tags: comics

> "Chuckles, then I might try to become President then!"

Do you use chuckles? Because chuckles is considered to be an onomatopoeia. I also considered "Haha", but it looks weird. How do comic books do this?

> "Haha, then I might try to become President then!"

The reason why Haha looks weird, is that you never emit a sound like "haha" when you chuckle.

I've seen the use of [Chuckle] in movie scripts, but I don't find it appealing and I haven't seen that in a text bubble in a comic book.

Comment: In https://www.zonanegativa.com/imagenes/2020/06/The-Spirit-1947-08-24-pag04-Shotdown-OctopusZN-600x811.jpg they use a variant of *chuckle*

Comment: It would help if we got the dialog that prompted your character's response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Chuckles" is not an onomatopoeia but a noun or verb (to chuckle) and it is not an interjection like "Haha!"

In this case, a number of options can be used such as one "Ha" or a "Huh", "hmm" or other similar.  The laugh may be more impulsive response like a "frrrt*" which is especially useful if the character is trying to suppress a laugh.  Using the acronym "LOL" or "ROFL" can be said by someone to denote they find amusement that should show laughter, but aren't impulsively laughing OR denote a sarcastic response indicating they are not amused.  Often it depends on age as a teen or someone addicted to text communications might say it out loud ("El Oh El", "Rawful") without Irony, while a character who is being sarcastic might use it to deliberately communicate the sarcasm to someone who they assume would only talk like this (Think Daffy Duck's sarcasm dripping line "HaHa HeeHee HoHo It is to laugh!" to convey to Porky or Bugs he's not enjoying their delight in his misfortune).

Consider the Simpsons characters of Edna Krabapple and Nelson Munz who have the catchphrases "Ha!" and "HaHa!" respecively.  The former can both be chuckles, but Edna's seems more impulsive (usually released in response to an idea she finds silly on the mere premise) while Nelson's goes from an impulse (done in response to a sudden incident as a genuine impulsive laugh) or a deliberate mockery of someone else's misfortune.

If you must use "chuckles" try to remove it from the dialog bubble and give a minor noted dialog outside of the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that HaHa would not suit for a chuckle. Better could be HeHe (He He). In fact, LoL is not exactly a chuckle but would look better than HaHa.